# Disabling the Not-Nullable field in ORACLE to insert NULL data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to add some NULL data into an otherwise not-nullable field. I checked :-

`ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP <default_constraint_name> ;`

`ALTER TABLE <table_name> ALTER COLUMN <column_name> <data_type> NULL;`

`ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP COLUMN <column_name>;`

but only the middle one seems fit for my usage because all I want o do is alter instead of . But it does not work. I am using Oracle 11g. Could you suggest anyother method or suggest what mistake I am doing in the 2nd ALTER TABLE SQL?

Comment: This is a dangerous practice, perhaps you should send the data back to get the required information instead of destroying the data integrity. Do not do this unless you are postive the need for not allowing nulls is definitely no longer there or you may break a lot of things and have bad data as well.  And do not do this without full regression testing.

Comment: What do you mean, "it does not work"?

Answer (score 1):

you can just disable constraint. And then enable it back when you want.

```
 alter table
    table_name
 ENABLE constraint
    constraint_name;

 alter table
    table_name
 DISABLE constraint
    constraint_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comment above, it may be a bad idea to allow NULLs in a column that previously did not allow them.  Queries or code that already exist may rely on the assumption that the field cannot contain NULL, and could experience various problems if that assumption becomes false (errors if you're lucky, quietly producing incorrect or incomplete results if you're not).

That said, the syntax to simply remove the NOT NULL constraint permanently is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name NULL;
```

You can also merely disable the constraint as indicated in another answer.  To do this you need the constraint name which you can find by querying `USER_CONSTRAINTS`.  This makes more sense if you expect to enable the constraint later.